# How to call reset type in reducer using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

event.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { addEvent } from '../actions/event';

const AddEvent = () => {
let history = useHistory();
const [event, setEvent] = useState();
const createEvent = useSelector(state => {
    console.log(state)
    return (
        state.addEvent
    )
});
const { loading, newEvent, success, error } = createEvent;
const handleChange = e => {
    setEvent({ ...event, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
    if(success) {
        history.push('/')  =========>>>>>>>> It work once fine but again when I tries to open add Event it automatically redirects to '/' as it is not getting reset after redirecting
    };
},[success]);
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(addEvent(event));
};

return (
    <div>
        { loading ? (
            <div> Loading... </div>
        ) : error ? (
            <div> {error} </div>
        ) : (
                    <form onSubmit={e => submitHandler(e)}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="name" className='mt-2'>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" name="name" onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="description" name="description" onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="userId">Assosicated User</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="userId" name='userId' onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
                        </div>
                        <Link to='/'> <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Back</button> </Link>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary float-right">Add Event</button>
                    </form>
                )}
    </div>
 )
};

export default AddEvent;
```

action.js

```
const addEvent = (newEvent) => async (dispatch) => {
 dispatch({ type: EVENT_ADD_REQUEST, payload:newEvent });
 try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3002/event`, newEvent);
    dispatch({ type: EVENT_ADD_SUCCESS, payload: data });
 }
 catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: EVENT_ADD_FAIL, payload:error.message });
 }
};
export {
 addEvent
};
```

reducer.js

```
function addEventReducer(state = {}, action ) {
switch(action.type) {
    case EVENT_ADD_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true, success:false };
    case EVENT_ADD_SUCCESS:
        return { loading:false, newEvent: action.payload, success:true };
    case EVENT_ADD_FAIL:
        return { loading:false, error: action.payload, success: false };
    case EVENT_RESET:
        return { ...state, loading:false, success: false };  ===========>>>>>>>> I want to call this for reset success to false so that it does not redirect again
    default:
        return state;
 };
};
export {
 addEventReducer
};
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { addEventReducer} from './reducers/event';

const reducer = combineReducers({
 addEvent: addEventReducer
});

const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
 reducer,
 composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

I am learning to work on react redux so I am trying crud workflow is working fine but after successful adding event I want it to redirect to homepage it is working fine but as react-redux holds it state so it is redirecting again to homepage as success is set to true so I have created another reset type to set success to false but not getting it how to call everytime after successfully adding data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

action.js

```
const addEvent = (newEvent) => async (dispatch) => {
dispatch({ type: EVENT_ADD_REQUEST, payload:newEvent });
 try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3002/event`, newEvent);
    dispatch({ type: EVENT_ADD_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    dispatch({ type: EVENT_RESET });  ===>>> adding here it works
 }
 catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: EVENT_ADD_FAIL, payload:error.message });
 }
};
```